# Problems with QObject multiple inheritance and policy/traits design in C++

Tags: c++, qt, multiple-inheritance, qobject

I'm building a fairly large plugin-driven app in my spare time, and have come across a show stopping design flaw.  My app uses policy/traits based design, but because I use Qt it is done just through MI (rather than templates and MI).  Some of these classes are pure virtual and some perform rather critical functions under the hood that the end-user should never touch.

My problem is that some of these classes require signals/slots and therefore derive from QObject, no problem I can just virtually inherit from it.  However, the problem I have is when I want derive from a Qt class and then extend it with one or more of my traits, eg:

```
class Sy_abstractGLViewport : public QGLWidget, public Sy_saveable, public Sy_abstractObject
{
    ...
}
```

Here QGLWidget is derived from QObject, but not virtually, causing ambiguity problems.

I've considered a Bridge pattern where I make for example my `Sy_saveable` pure virtual and then derive a `Sy_saveable_imp` from it that contains the actual implementation.  Then use that for my `Sy_abstractGLViewport` via aggregation.

This to me seems rather unprofessional, because the app is plugin based, it's a bit of a PITA for my future plugin writers to 'hook up' all the interface methods to the aggregated instance.  I can't even automate it through macros because the end-user may want to override a method.

Has anyone a pattern to solve this issue?  Or a pattern that doesn't require MI but gives me the same flexibility?  This my personal hobby project, I don't mind doing a lot of refactoring - I want to do it *right*.

Comment: Not sure if you doing this or not, but I would not virtually inherit from QObject. It works in qt 4.7 and before, but might not in qt 4.8. See https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-19717

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't inherit from multiples clasess that inherit QObject.

Try using composition instead of inheritance. See [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

You can also try using [Q3Signal](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.3/q3signal.html) class. Although it belongs to old QT3 according to QT doc :

> The Q3Signal class can be used to send signals for classes that don't
>   inherit QObject.

Comment: You can inherit from QObject multiple times as long as it is declared as virtual inheritance in the parent classes - but Qt's own classes don't.  And the problem with composition is that is allows the user to essentially override methods that shouldn't be (because I'm relying them to build the accessor methods properly), or to simply not build the relevant accessors.

Comment: No, you are not supposed to use virtual inheritance with QObjects (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/moc.html#multiple-inheritance-requires-qobject-to-be-first).  Don't do it, you will run into weird behavior even if your code compiles.

Comment: Well because I'm lazy and therefore don't like composition, I've had to concede that it's my only way out of this.  I've managed to retain my is_a relationships by making my old traits classes interfaces, and then creating 'implementation' classes from them which the end-user derives from for their aggregated member.